# for loop using dictionary but only works if the key is a single character

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I tried to make a mini language translator using dictionary and for loop but it only works if the key is a single character. If the key is more than 2 letters, it prints out the default value. What's the problem?

```
words_to_translate = input("Please type the words to translate ")
eng_to_ger = {
    "apple": "apfel",
    "black": "schwarz",
    "1": "eins",
    "2": "zwei",
    "3": "drie",
    " ": " "
}
output = ""
for words in words_to_translate:
    output += eng_to_ger.get(words, "!")
print(output)
```

For example:
If I input `1 2`,  it prints out `eins zwei` as desired but when I input `apple` it prints out `!!!!!`

Comment: You are looping through a string, and that causes the string to be broken into individual characters.  You need to split words_to_translate into individual words, using something like words_to_translate.split(' ').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` returns a string. When you iterate over a string, it iterates over single characters. I.e.

```
my_str = "abcdef"
for e in my_str:
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

What you really want is to iterate over words, which can be done by splitting the string on whitespaces. So you can do this via `.split()` :

```
words_to_translate = input("Please type the words to translate ").split() # splits on whitespace by default (i.e. space/tabs)

for word in words_to_translate:
    # rest of the code
```